# Pythagorean triple calculation in java

Tags: java

I found a way to calculate all the Pythagorean triple until a certain number,but my program duplicates some , just in different order . How can i avoid this? i try to organize the Pythagorean triple by c value (a*a+b*b=c*c)
this is my code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Number;
        Number = s.nextInt();
        for(int c=1;c<Number;c++){
            for(int b=1;b<Number;b++){
                for(int a=1;a<Number-2;a++){
                    if(a*a + b*b == c*c)
                        System.out.println("("+a+","+b+","+c+") : "+a+"*"+a+" + "+b+"*"+b+" = "+c+"*"+c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make this change:

```
    for(int c=1;c<Number;c++){
        for(int b=1;b<c;b++){
            for(int a=1;a<b;a++){
                if(a*a + b*b == c*c )
```

but be aware that the are even more efficient methods such as Euclid's formula